# Converting dataframe column into onehotencoder like columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to find the solution to convert specific column into onehotencoder type columns. For example

```
-------------
Content|type|
-------------
alpha  | A  |
beta   | B  |
gamma  | C  |
theta  | A  |
zeta   | C  |
neta   | B  |
-------------
```

And, what I am trying to do is following.

```
----------------------------
Content|type_A|type_B|type_C|
----------------------------
alpha  |  1   |  0   |  0   |
beta   |  0   |  1   |  0   |
gamma  |  0   |  0   |  1   |
theta  |  1   |  0   |  0   |
zeta   |  0   |  0   |  1   |
neta   |  0   |  1   |  0   |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Have you looked into sparkML one hot encoder ? Or pivot functions ?

Comment: As far as I know: The one hot encoder return back the array having length of unique elements in column. And, the pivot function has dependency on groupBy function in order to get any aggregate of column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `pivot` is what you are looking for

```
val df = Seq(
  ("alpha", "A"),
  ("beta", "B"),
  ("gamma", "C"),
  ("theta", "A"),
  ("zeta", "C"),
  ("neta", "B")
).toDF("Content", "type")

val result = df.groupBy("Content")
  .pivot("type")
  .agg(count("type"))
  .na.fill(0)
```

Output:

```
+-------+---+---+---+
|Content|A  |B  |C  |
+-------+---+---+---+
|neta   |0  |1  |0  |
|beta   |0  |1  |0  |
|gamma  |0  |0  |1  |
|theta  |1  |0  |0  |
|zeta   |0  |0  |1  |
|alpha  |1  |0  |0  |
+-------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Instead of column name as "A","B" and "C", can we achieve adding prefix (type) like "Type_A" using above code? Or, we have to manually change it?

Comment: Sure you can add alias for it but only works if you have more then one `agg`, otherwise you have to do it manually.